# numba for scipy, specifically cdist

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, numba

I'm trying to speed up a comparison between two pointclouds, I have some code which took up to an hour to complete. I've butchered it to this and tried to implement numba. The code works with the exception of the scipy cdist function. It's my first test of using numba, where am I going wrong?

```
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def near_dist_top(T, B):
    xi = [i[0] for i in T]
    yi = [i[1] for i in T]
    zi = [i[2] for i in T]
    XB = B

    insert_params = []

    for i in range(len(T)):
        XA = [T[i]]
        disti = cdist(XA, XB, metric='euclidean').min()
        insert_params.append((xi[i], yi[i], zi[i], disti))
        # print("Top: " + str(i) + " of " + str(len(T)))
        print(i)
    return insert_params
    print(XB)
```

@@@ Edits @@@

Both T and B are lists of coordinates

```
(580992.507, 4275268.8321, 192.4599), (580992.507, 4275268.8391, 192.4209), (580992.507, 4275268.8391, 192.4209)
```

hmmm, does numba handle lists, does it need to be a numpy array, would cdist handle a numpy array...?

The error

```
numba.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'cdist': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>

File "scratch_28.py", line 132:
def near_dist_top(T, B):
    <source elided>
        XA = [T[i]]
        disti = cdist(XA, XB, metric='euclidean').min()
        ^
```

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace ? Also, what does the argument T and B contain ?

Comment: What sor t of error?  LIke something about not being able to implement `cdist`?  How, by the way, are you importing or defining `cdist`?  It's not 'native' `numpy`.

Comment: ok, I've updated the question

Comment: cdist is brought in using `from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist`

Comment: Is `cdist` in the list of of functions that can be handled with 'nopython'?

Comment: I'm assuming that's the issue, although I converted the nested list to a numpy array and I saw a x10 speed improvement (from 30 minutes to 3 minutes) and it looks like its invoking the GPU (my GPU active light turns on). So the question is: is scipy within numba? Any idea where the numba list is?

Comment: Here's the list, cdist doesn't seem to be there, min() is though so the speed improvement might be related to that (although I doubt it)? https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html

Comment: `numba` seeks to implement a large part of `numpy`.  `scipy` is a collection of addons to `numpy` - generally scientific and math that uses `numpy`, but it is not tightly integrate with `numpy` or with itself.  So while `scipy` code uses `numpy` code, you should not assume that `numpy` itself is aware of `scipy` distinctives - and that would apply to `numba` as well.

Comment: so I assume cdist is not compatible with numba?

Comment: How large are the lists you are working on? It looks like you are searching for a nearest neighbour search. In this case a kdtree solution https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html will outperform the best brute-force Numba solution on larger arrays. Apart from that there are several possibilities to implement cdist to numba eg. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53380192/4045774