# How to get nearest neighbor for every element of array A from array B

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn, computer-vision

I need to create function `nearest_neighbor(src, dst)`, which accepts two arrays of 2D points, and for every point of array A calculates distance and index to closest neighbor from array B.

Example input:

```
src = np.array([[1,1], [2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[9,9]])
dst = np.array([[6,7],[10,10],[10,20]])
```

Example output:

```
(array([7.81024968, 6.40312424, 5.        , 3.60555128, 1.41421356]),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1]))
```

With  sklearn you can do it like this:

```
def nearest_neighbor(src, dst):
    neigh = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=1)
    neigh.fit(dst)
    distances, indices = neigh.kneighbors(src, return_distance=True)
    return distances.ravel(), indices.ravel()
```

But i need to create it only with numpy. I made it like this:

```
def nearest_neighbor(src, dst):
    distances = []
    indices = []
    
    
    for dot in src:
        dists = np.linalg.norm(dst - dot,axis=1)
        dist = np.min(dists)
        idx = np.argmin(dists)
        
        distances.append(dist)
        indices.append(idx)

    return np.array(distances), np.array(indices)
```

But it works slow because of python cycle. How I can make it faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [broadcast](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.broadcasting.html), `src[:, None] - dst` make each row of `src` subtract each row of `dst`:

```
>>> def nearest_neighbor(src, dst):
...     dist = np.linalg.norm(src[:, None] - dst, axis=-1)
...     indices = dist.argmin(-1)
...     return dist[np.arange(len(dist)), indices], indices
...
>>> src = np.array([[1,1], [2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[9,9]])
>>> dst = np.array([[6,7],[10,10],[10,20]])
>>> nearest_neighbor(src, dst)
(array([7.81024968, 6.40312424, 5.        , 3.60555128, 1.41421356]),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1], dtype=int64))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html):

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

# compute matrix of distances
dist = cdist(src, dst)

# get min distance
closest = dist.argmin(axis=1)
# array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1])

distance = dist[np.arange(src.shape[0]), closest]
#array([7.81024968, 6.40312424, 5.        , 3.60555128, 1.41421356])
```

Comment: I think `cdist` will be the fastest method among the proposed answers, which may could be faster if utilize a equivalent numba ([similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72566612/13394817)) code instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should read on numpy broadcasting:

```
dist = np.square(src[:,None] - dst).sum(axis=-1) ** .5

idx = dist.argmin(axis=-1)
# array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1])

min_dist = dist[np.arange(len(dist)), idx]
```

Comment: Note that, if you compute the distance manually, you can take the square root only after subsetting the min distance , this saves you some CPU ;)